# Replacing a presence value of "1" with the field name of the column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have unique plot numbers in my first column. Then at the top of all other columns I have plant names:

```
      Acer   Quercus  Carya
```

Plot1___1________1________1

Plot2___1

Plot3 ___________1________1

Plot4__1__________________1

The 1's represent presence, but I want to replace the 1 with the name that's referenced at the top of the column. I have thousands of plots and hundreds of tree species, so it needs to be automated. Sorry for the awful formatting above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBA snippet should do the trick.

```
Dim column As Integer
For column = 2 To 4 ' Replace from column 2(B) to 4(D).
    ' Replace each occurance of "1" in the column with the header text.
    Columns(column).Replace "1", Cells(1, column).Value
Next
```

Just adjust the column number(s) to evaluate according to how many columns you need to process.

Comment: @Sunny, you should mark the answer for future users and also to show your appreciation for Jason's solution.